# How to change configuration option in Kendo UI ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

We're using Kendo UI via MVC wrappers.
Here's how we create a MultiSelect:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
              .Name("filterUsers")
              .DataTextField("Text")
              .DataValueField("Value")
              .Placeholder("Select users...")...
```

The problem is that in new version of Kendo UI there's an option `clearButton` which has no wrapper in MVC.

How can we set it while continue using MVC wrappers? I tried:

1) Data attributes (`data-clear-button`), but it doesn't work since it requires all settings to be defined via attributes and the widget to be created via `kendo.Bind`

2) Altering configuration via `setOptions`, which doesn't work:

```
$(function() {
  var s = $("#multiselect").data('kendoMultiSelect');
  s.setOptions({clearButton: false});
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you really want a native solution? Because this *hack* `$($("#multiselect").data("kendoMultiSelect").wrapper).find(".k-i-close").css("display", "none")` seems to work fine.

Comment: I was sure the native solution exists, but it turns out, it's not.. I actually mentioned ClearButton as a good example, it seems I'll need to find hacks for other options as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestion of **DontVoteMeDown** can work for *specific* MultiSelects, but needs a modification:

```
$("#multiselect").data("kendoMultiSelect").wrapper
    .find(".k-multiselect-wrap > .k-i-close").css("display", "none");
```

Otherwise the previously suggested implementation will also hide the close buttons for any pre-selected items.

If you want to target *all* MultiSelects, then use one of the following instead:

**CSS**

```
.k-multiselect-wrap > .k-i-close {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

or

**JavaScript**

```
// execute this before any MultiSelects are initialized
kendo.ui.MultiSelect.fn.options.clearButton = false;
```

Comment: It seems I could use `kendo.ui.MultiSelect.fn.options.clearButton = false;` before creating a select, and set it back to `true` after creation. That's still a hack, but the cleanest one till now :)